# FreeBSD: How to check how many threads are running in a process by PID?

Tags: c, multithreading, freebsd, procfs

In Linux I can do this by checking the /proc/pid/status file and looking for a line: Threads: 1 (or any number). How can I achieve the same in FreeBSD? I am not interested in any interactive tool. Is there any C function, or a system file? I have tried BSD's procfs and and linprocfs and I could not find any similair feature there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want:

`procstat -t <pid>`

This answer is short, but I'm typing more to get the answer up to the minimum length.

Comment: Good breadcrumb, but the question asked for a C function or /proc file. The place to look for the C API calls used appears to be: https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-src/blob/main/usr.bin/procstat/procstat_basic.c or https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-src/blob/main/usr.bin/procstat/procstat_threads.c